# Как вызвать функцию в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот, telegram

```
import telebot 
from telebot import types
token="......"
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup_Inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2) # Активация клавиатуры
    Inline_B3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пропустить", callback_data="CONTINUE")
    .....
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == "CONTINUE":
                start() # это не помогло. start(message) это тоже

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Comment: Кто не понял нужно по нажатии кнопки вызывать функцию start()

Comment: какой кнопки? О чем вы? Вот в этой строке сказанно когда это произойдет ```bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])```, а именно когда будет отправлена команда ```start```

Comment: Да ну?? Правда чтоли? А я и не понял что эта строка bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) вызывается при введении /start в чате. Если вы хоть знакомы с telebot , то должны знать что      
Inline_B3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пропустить", callback_data="CONTINUE") ""условное"" создания каркаса кнопки , при нажатии которой, должна вызываться функция start(), но так как я не знаю как это сделать обратился за помощью!! @ВладимирКлыков

Comment: Здесь ОДНА кнопка, не миллион. Так же как и одна функция , которую надо вызвать.Что за глупые вопросы!?!?!?!